# React Native - Nothing was returned from render

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

My application is stored in /src/index.js but i also have a /App.js and a /index.js.

I don't know the difference between these and i think thats the reason im getting this error.

[image]

**/index.js**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('client', () => App);
```

**/App.js**

```
import App from './src/index';

export default App;
```

**/src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';

import Navigator from './routes/route';
import store from './store/configureStore';


const App = ({ dispatch, nav }) => {

    <Navigator
        navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
            dispatch,
            state: nav,
        })}
    />
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    nav: state.nav,
});



const AppWithNavigation = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

export default () => {

    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppWithNavigation />
    </Provider>

}
```

I used create react native package to build this project and then tried to follow some guides to implement react navigation with redux.

Comment: you haven't exported `App` in index.js that you're importing in App.js

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your default export is not returning anything :

```
export default () => {

    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppWithNavigation />
    </Provider>

}
```

To return JSX with an arrow function you need to use `() => ( <JSX /> )` or the equivalent with curly braces : `() => { return ( <JSX /> ) }` :

```
export default () => (    
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppWithNavigation />
    </Provider>
)
```

or :

```
export default () => {
    return (    
       <Provider store={store}>
           <AppWithNavigation />
       </Provider>
   )
}
```

Comment: before i was getting Component nothing was rendered, after ur change im getting App nothing was rendered

Comment: oh you need to change your app component too it's the same mistake

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to `return` the `components`

```
const App = ({ dispatch, nav }) => {
    return(
        <Navigator
            navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
                dispatch,
                state: nav,
            })}
        />
    )
};


export default () => {
    return(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AppWithNavigation />
        </Provider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't mention this

```
import React from 'react';
```

and all other `react-native` components in my other files of screens.

Because I was calling my screen component from another file, from App.js file, so I also had to import react and react-native components in that file too.